# JUnit for GQL Query

Tags: gqlquery

Please can you help me writing junits for below method,

```
public Map<String, List<Entity>> getEntitiesUsingAncestorKey(Key ancestorKey) {
    QueryResults<Entity> queryResults;
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
    queryString.append("SELECT * WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR @ancestorKey");
    Query<Entity> query = Query.newGqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY, queryString.toString())
            .setBinding("ancestorKey", ancestorKey)
            .build();
    queryResults = datastore.run(query);
    return StreamSupport.stream(
            Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(queryResults, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entity -> entity.getKey().getKind()));
}
```

How to mock QueryResults..?